# PHP script to convert documents and images to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, doc

I'm looking for a way to convert bunch of images and `.doc` file into PDF using PHP. Is there any script available for this?

I'm not looking for anything that requires me to install an application on the server to use this. Can it be done using PHP only?

Comment: A simple search should show several similar questions.  From experience, none of the PHP libraries are a great replacement for existing utilities like LibreOffice/OpenOffice for document conversion.

Comment: You maybe right, but I'm looking for something in the web interface terms and not an application.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at tcpdf.

https://tcpdf.org/examples/

Comment: Can you explain with an example how to use this library? Is there any script that can be used without a library because libraries come will a lot of stuff that is not really required?

Comment: You can have a look at their examples.Include the file in your code. The most basic example will be https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_001/. It's beyond the scope to explain in detail here. However, I am not sure if you will be able to achieve it without a library.